# Ng2-Charts Linechart only showing first 2 two values

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I'm starting new Angular application which I initialised with Angular-CLI (beta 22.1). But when I add test-data (5 values) to my chart it seems to scale wrong and only shows the first two values and streched them over the whole length of the graph (see picture).

[image]

The project is otherwise blank and does not contain any CSS whatsoever.

My `app.component.html`:

```
<div>
    <canvas baseChart [datasets]="_numbers" [labels]="_labels" [options]="_chartOpt" [colors]="_chartColours" [legend]="_chartLegend" [chartType]="_chartType" width="600px">
    </canvas>
<div>
```

The `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseChartDirective } from "ng2-charts/ng2-charts";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private _numbers: any[] = [
      {
        label: "Test",
        data: [10,2,6,7] // should cause 4 points in the chart
     }
  ];

  private _chartOpt: any = {
        responsive: true
  };

  public _chartColours:any[] = [];

  private _labels: string[] = [];
  private _chartLegend: boolean = false;
  private _chartType: string = "line";
}
```

The *chart.js* library is added via the `angular-cli.json`:

```
"scripts": [
         "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"
      ],
```

I really don't know where I'm going wrong. I've tried many different options (`responsive: true/false`, `maintainAspectRatio : true/false`, wrapping the `<canvas>` in `<div>` and without, CSS Styles, width/height attributes, ...) but can't seem to get this one to work. I even downgraded the ng2-charts version to one that I reviously worked with, but with no luck.

Let me know if you need anymore code.

Comment: Have you tried assigning `labels`? Like real values, not empty string array? Maybe a silly question, I haven't used this charts myself, but still, the documentation says: "It's necessary for charts: line, bar and radar"

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin Thanks for the hint. That was actually it... Be my guest to write it up as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad it helped! Posted as an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`labels` property must be defined along with values. According to documentation for [properties](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts#properties):

> labels (?Array) - x axis labels. It's necessary for charts: line, bar and radar.

So specifying actual values for labels will do the trick.

Comment: In chatJS documentation, when data is array of point object, labels may be undefined. So when i'm using array of point, with x time based value, i have the same beahvior : only 2 points are shown

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a condition inside the canvas, e.g., show it when the data is loaded or your `array.length > 0`

Example:

```
<canvas baseChart *ngIf="showMyChart" [datasets]="_numbers"
     [chartType]="_chartType" width="600px">
</canvas>
```