# Only first value added gets displayed in ng2-chart linechart

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

I have a very simple line chart where I want to add values when a user clicks on a button. But for whatever reason only the first value added (after initial values) will get displayed and all values afterwards are kind of cut of.

[image]

I'm aware of [this very similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41248525/ng2-charts-linechart-only-showing-first-2-two-values) but I'm already using labels and it's still not working correctly for me.

I've made a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/tZBaDgcejij1r1LjJAAZ?p=preview) version of my problem, but here is basically my code:

Template:

```xml
<div style="display: block">
    <canvas baseChart
            [options]="chartOptions"
            [data]="chartData"
            [labels]="chartLabels"
            [chartType]="chartType"></canvas>
</div>

<button (click)="addRandomValue()">Add Random value</button>
```

Component:

```js
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {
    public chartType: string;

    public chartData: number[];
    public chartLabels: string[];

    public chartOptions: any = {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false
    };

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.chartType = 'line';
        this.chartLabels = [ '1', '2', '3' ];
        this.chartData = [ 0, 10, 20 ];
    }

    addRandomValue(): void {
        this.chartData.push(Math.random() * 10 + 10);
        this.chartLabels.push(this.chartData.length + '');

        // weird workaround for refreshing data, works fine
        // for all other chart types I tried it on
        this.chartData = this.chartData.slice();
        this.chartLabels = this.chartLabels.slice();
    }
}
```

Is this some kind of bug or does anyone know how to work around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the slice of the labels, that should do the trick

Which means your addRandomValue() should look like this:

```
addRandomValue(): void {
    this.chartData.push(Math.random() * 10 + 10);
    this.chartLabels.push(this.chartData.length + '');

    // weird workaround for refreshing data, works fine
    // for all other chart types I tried it on
    this.chartData = this.chartData.slice();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a somewhat known issue. If you look at the examples for ng2-chart you'll notice a comment written beneath the declaration of the bar-chart (https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/blob/master/demo/src/app/components/charts/bar-chart-demo.ts).

To put it in a nutshell, you have to clone the data, get your CRUD done on the clone, and reassign the data to the original variable so the change is recognized.